# Google Cloud Platform - GCP Proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I ran on my terminal

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances={$my_instance$}=tcp:3308
```

Then I could go onto

```
Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306
Ready for new connection
```

Then nothing happens afterward.

I don't understand why it's not connecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command is used for starting the proxy in its own terminal so you can monitor its output.

./cloud_sql_proxy -instances==tcp:3306

In a different terminal window from where you started the proxy, run the following command, replacing  with your MySQL username.

mysql -u  -p --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3306

When you connect using TCP sockets, the proxy is accessed through 127.0.0.1.
Enter the password.
You should see the mysql prompt.A message similar to the following should appear in the proxy terminal:

New connection for "myproject:us-central1:myinstance"

Recommend this the article “[Connecting MySQL client using the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy)” for you setup and troubleshooting.

Comment: thanks! let me try first :)